Spring Cloud Gateway Encoded Slash Issue After Upgrade
I just recently updated my Spring Cloud Gateway that I use as a proxy to other Microservices to java 21 (upgraded from java 8), Spring 3.2.. (upgraded from 2.7.3) and Spring cloud 2023.0. (upgraded from 2021.0.1) but I just noticed I can't that it no longer accepts requests with encoded slashes (%2F) in the request; it returns a 400 error.
Has anyone else experienced this and fixed it? Was there a breaking change between these versions?
I also had this issue with the microservices but was able to fix this by adding WebServerFactoryCustomizer for tomcat that allows encoded slashes but this fix doesn't work for the Gateway.
